# Why are user imputed values growing largely in value after input via Console.Read();

Tags: c#, math, console-application

I am making a console program and I am trying to read values from user input. If a user inputs a value like 1, it ends up as 49. I believe the input code: `int classicPlant = Console.Read()` is the problem, but I don't know why, or if it even is. 
I have made sure it is not the fault of the operations I am performing on it because I have tested it in a seperate program. Any idea how these numbers could be growing in value?

Comment: Sorry for the snippet that didn't end up in the code format. I'll try to edit that out.

Comment: Your "whole program" wouldn't compile, but your question is largely unintelligible as it's currently written - try to narrow down on *just* what's needed to reproduce your issue in a full example that *compiles and runs*. You'll likely find your issue in the process of doing so, but if you don't, update your question with *that* code. http://sscce.org/

Comment: First thing, the line **double classicLPD = classicTrees*= 0.5;** sets classicTrees to 3, which is why you get 3 there instead of 6.

Comment: I suspect when you think you are doing 3 + 1, and 3 -1, you have accidentally changed your values using += or something, per my previous comment. As a guess, print the variables you think are 3 and 1, check they aren't say, 4 and 48

Comment: Set a breakpoint and debug your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int classicPlant = Console.Read()` is the culprit.

`Console.Read` returns the character value of the item input. In ASCII, '1' = 49, and '3' = 51.

`'1' - 1 == 48`
`'3' + 1 == 52`

Hence, fix the `Read` to use `Integer.Parse()` or check the range and subtract 48 or something similar

Comment: And in case it wasn't clear, `classicLimes` is 5, and `5 - '1' == -44`